# Self-merge a data frame with a lag in R?

Tags: r, merge

Here is some R code to merge foo with itself with a 1-day lag:

```
foo <- data.frame(user=c(10,10,10,11,11,11),
                  day=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  something=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'))
foo$prev_day <- foo$day - 1
foo2 <- merge(foo, foo,
                by.x=c('user', 'day'),
                by.y=c('user', 'prev_day'))

#Warning message:
#In merge.data.frame(foo, foo, by.x = c("user", "day"), by.y = c("user",  :
#  column name ‘day’ is duplicated in the result

foo2

  user day something.x prev_day day something.y
1   10   1           a        0   2           b
2   10   2           b        1   3           c
3   11   1           d        0   2           e
4   11   2           e        1   3           f
```

Notice that it complains and has 'day' in the result twice, but otherwise looks pretty good (each user only merged with itself).

What is the easiest way to do this properly, i.e. no warning and only having the first 'day' column and not the second in the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the "day" column from the second dataset to avoid the clash between `by=` variables and other existing variables.

```
merge(foo, foo[!names(foo) %in% "day"],
      by.x=c("user","day"),
      by.y=c("user","prev_day"))
```